# Toyota corolla verso 1.794 petrol vvt-1-t2

Tags: engine, toyota, oil, corolla, compression-testing

Recently Purchased Vehicle @milage 81.075 in the past vehicle has consumed 5.25 Litres of oil a full oil composition test was carried by my Garage. They also advise it is an uneconomical repair it has no oil leaks the oil is going out
via the catalytic converter the car sales agents said they would do an engine compression test by one of their Sales People I Instructed my Garage to do one
on my behalf the report is as follows on a DRY Test on

cyl One 175

Cyl TWO 110

cyl Three 110

cyl Four 120

Please Advise

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Can you update your question so it is clear what you what to know?

Comment: Are you assessing a new vehicle to buy or is this......Can you clarify your statement?  All due respect, I have no clue what you want.

Comment: He says "recently purchased" so I'm working on the assumption that he is the purchaser.

Answer (score 0):

Those compression readings are too unbalanced and 3 of 4 are too low, even for a worn engine.

Your only options are returning the vehicle or getting the seller to pay for a full rebuild. If they will not do either, get a lawyer.